# Array React Hooks

Tags: array, reactjs, react-hooks

Se tiene un array

```
[
  { id: 1, nombre: 'Camisa ReactJS', precio: 50, cantidad: 10 },
  { id: 2, nombre: 'Camisa VueJS', precio: 40, cantidad: 12 },
  { id: 3, nombre: 'Camisa Node.js', precio: 30, cantidad: 14 },
  { id: 4, nombre: 'Camisa Angular', precio: 20, cantidad: 16 },
]
```

y deseo que al oprimir un botón la 'cantidad' se reduzca de 1 en 1.

Answer (score 0):

Recorre la lista con `.map` por ejemplo, buscas que id quieres actualizar y modificas la respuesta, tal que así:

```js
lista.map(item => {
  if (item.id === id) {
    return { ...item, cantidad: item.cantidad - 1 }
  }
  return item;
});
```